# Python Hex-String to Hex-String with Backslash

Tags: python, hex

I'm really confused, with Byte-Strings in Python.

I need to compare two Byte-Strings, so they should be converted the same (?)

I have a String of Hex-Values:

> 52fab71f49a01ef92e793b41c13c5458080679919c7e5888f195935bd50c1bb8

If I convert this to a Byte-String with `bytes.fromHex('52fab...')` I get:

> b'R\xfa\xb7\x1fI\xa0\x1e\xf9.y;A\xc1<TX\x08\x06y\x91\x9c~X\x88\xf1\x95\x93[\xd5\x0c\x1b\xb8'

But I want the `'R'` at the beginning as `'0x52'`. How can I achieve this? 
Why do I get `'R'` instead of `'0x52'`? As Example, for the 2nd Byte, I get `'0xfa'` for `'fa'`.

Same Problem with the other Ascii "Letter" like 'y', ';', 'A' ...

I hope this is not too confusing - I haven't found a appropriate solution after a long research.

Greetings

Daniel

Comment: I don't see any `0x52`.

Comment: What is the other calue you want to compare with ? share it

Comment: In my case, I have a ByteString \x00...\x00\x01\x01'
I want to Increment the last two Bytes, hash them (with SHA256) and compare those Hashes with the given String of Hex-Values '52fa...' (which is a SHA256-Hash aswell) - and validate if i got the right hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

If you're using the standard `bytes` type, that's what its string representation is going to look like: it will represent all ASCII characters as themselves. For example, `b'\x42'` is the ASCII `'R'` character, so it'll be printed as itself.

Of course, you can create your own function to get the output you want, like:

```
def print_me(thing: bytes):
    print(''.join(
        f'\\x{byte:02x}'
        for byte in thing
    ))

>>> print_me(bytes.fromhex("52fab71f49a01ef92e793b41c13c5458080679919c7e5888f195935bd50c1bb8"))
\x52\xfa\xb7\x1f\x49\xa0\x1e\xf9\x2e\x79\x3b\x41\xc1\x3c\x54\x58\x08\x06\x79\x91\x9c\x7e\x58\x88\xf1\x95\x93\x5b\xd5\x0c\x1b\xb8
```

but the underlying data stored in your `bytes` object will still be the same, no matter how you represent it.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer!
Do I have any chances, to compare 'R' and '0x52' ? 
I'm really confused with these encode/decode Stuff.

Comment: @ZoellnD, once you convert your hex to bytes with `bytes.fromhex`, you'll be able to compare it to other `bytes` objects. `b'R'` and `b'\x52'` are the _exact_ same

Comment: I have no Idea what I did wrong - but yes, this is working! Thank you!!